# .Contains() in .Where() EF Core doesn't work .NET Core 3.1.8

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the the following code that doesn't work:

```
var bookIds = source.Sids.Split(",");            
     
var hkm = _context.Books
                .Include(b => b.Writer)
                .Where(b => bookIds.Contains(b.SttmId.toString()))
                .ToList();
```

To clarify the code above a bit more:

```
// kinda same like the code above (just to clarify what source is):
// This doesn't work
 
var bookIds = "2194".Split(",");    
 
var hkm = _context.Books
                .Include(b => b.Writer)
                .Where(b => bookIds.Contains(b.SttmId.toString()))
                .ToList();
 
// This works
 
var bookIds = 2194;    
 
var hkm = _context.Books
                .Include(b => b.Writer)
                .Where(b => b.SttmId == bookIds))
                .ToList();
```

`b.SttmId` is of the type Nullable Long: `long?`

I get a strange error:

> ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression
> 'DbSet
> .Where(s => __BooksIds_0
> .Contains(b.SttmId.ToString()))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch
> to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either
> AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

Am I doing something wrong or is there something wrong with EF Core?

Comment: I also tried: `Convert.ToString(b.SttmId)` that also didn't work.

Comment: What type is b.SttmId? Have you tried making your array the same type as the db property?

Comment: Hi @CaiusJard in the question I mentioned that it's of type `long?` :)

Comment: Sorry, I think your edit crossed with my comment- didn't see you mention it as long

Comment: @OS What is the database you are using? SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle?

Comment: @atiyar I'm using Sqlite.

Comment: it's strange that this works perfectly fine in .net core 2.2 (efcore 2.2.6). There should be no reason to make it not supported.

Comment: btw, can you try this `.Where(b => bookIds.Contains(b.SttmId.Value))` (`bookIds`'s element type is `long`) or `.Where(b => bookIds.Contains(b.SttmId))` (`bookIds`'s element type is `long?`) ? Those both work perfectly fine in .net core 2.2 (efcore 2.2.6) as well.

Comment: @KingKing prior to 3.0, client side evaluation would happen automatically if the query could not be translated to sql. In 3.0+, they now require you to be explicit about it... Likely because people were writing atrocious linq statements, assuming the queries were happening on the server when in reality the entire table would be brought client side so that the evaluation could happen there without the dev realizing it

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 it's a pity that I've never had a chance to try .net core 3.0+ (maxi at .net 2.2). However I know about that automatic conversion to client-side query evaluation. And I know that we can configure it to not behave like that by using `.ConfigureWarnings(e => e.Throw())` when configuring the dbContext. I've tried that as well and no exception is thrown. Actually no even an warning is printed (if not using that configuration).

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 well actually my case works because I tested against `SQL Server` whereas the OP is `SQLite`, here the generated sql server query from my simple test `... WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), [e].[Point]) IN (N'1', N'2')` - which is completely valid. That however may not be supported by `SQLite provider`. Forgot about the OP using `SQLite`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
var bookIds = new long[] { 2194 };

var hkm = _context.Books
                  .Include(b => b.Writer)
                  .Where(b => bookIds.Any(x => x == b.SttmId))
                  .ToArray();
```

And if so all you have to do is arrange an array of longs e.g

```
var bookIds = "1 2 3 4".Split().Select(x => long.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Why would `.Where(b => bookIds.Contains(b.SttmId))` not work?

Comment: Are you saying it doesn't?

Comment: Isn't that is what's not working with OP's code?

Comment: Doesn't work, explanation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#unsupported-client-evaluation

Answer (score 0):

I ran similar code but without `.Include(b => b.Writer)` (thinks it doesn't matter) and it works.
May be this depends on database management system or EntityFrameworkCore version? I use SQL server and EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.1

Comment: I will try that. I use `EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.8`

Comment: Still the same error even if I remove `Include()`.

Comment: I might try to upgrade my .NET Core and the entityframework packages.

Comment: @OS I don't think it is related to your .NET/EF version. I ran your code with EF Core 3.1 and it works.

Comment: @atiyar it indeed isn't related to .NET/EF version.